# What kind of knowledge and technologies needed to develop an specific mobile app?

Tags: android, mobile

I had chosen to develop an mobile app for my final year project. The app is an parenting application that help parent to monitor and control screen time of their children and it have some function such as:
- Send notification to the parent mobile device when the child start to use the device.
- Lock the phone at certain time or by choice.
- Location tracking (optional)
- Report on use-time.

I'm familiar with basic Java and Android programming.

So what are the other knowledge (technology, mechanism, etc) that i will needed to develop this app.

Comment: This question is not related with programming.

Comment: i'm new here, so what seem to be the problem with "this question not related with programming"?

Comment: You're new, but you're always shown tips to ask a good question before writing it. Your question isn't related to programming in general and is too broad. StackOverflow is a site to ask questions related to programming. When people try something, and if they face a problem with their code/it is not working as expected, then they ask a question here. For ex. if you tried coding for "locking the device at certain time", but then faced problem while doing it, you can ask a question here so that other people can take a look at it. Also, your question is overly broad, you can work on that too.

Comment: Hope that solves your concern. This site may feel rough and harsh in the start, but eventually you'll realise that these rules keep this site as the top site to look for any concern related to programming. Welcome to StackOverflow. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want to create parental control app and you can create it using "Android Management API"

Please refer [Android Management API](https://developers.google.com/android/management/introduction)

Many companies installs this kind of apps in their employees company owned devices, many parents install this kind of apps in their child's mobiles to monitor their data usage, applications usage, their driving speeds etc.

Best of luck.